# Обновление данных в БД

Tags: node.js, express

В общем, необходимо раз в час-два вызывать функцию, которая будет обновлять данные в БД(если это необходимо). Написал вот такой вариант (без бд, просто получение данных). На сколько оптимально использовать setIntervals и есть ли какие-то другие варианты?

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

const getDataFromCb = async ()=>{
    fetch('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js').then(async(result)=>{
    if(result.status===200 && result.ok){
        return result.json();

    }
    }).then((JSON_DATA)=>{
        console.log('Список получен ', JSON_DATA)
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.error("Ошибка", error)
    })
}
setInterval(getDataFromCb,10000)
```

Comment: Неадекватно на таких значениях(несколько часов). https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а в чём фундаментальная разница node-schedule и setInterval?

Comment: Принципом работы, setinterval - очень не точен и не надежен на таких интервалах, если упрощенно - вы можете делать setinterval на 1 минуту, и проверять каждый раз не наступило ли время вашей задачи(не прошло ли уже 60 минут...), но напрямую использовать setinterval на больших диапазонах - моветон.

Comment: он не очень точен в миллисекундном диапазоне, что не так уж важно на дистанции в часы и при сетевых задержках при запросе. расскажите, пожалуйста, в чём фундаментальная разница node-schedule и setInterval (для этой задачи)?

Comment: вот, что [под капотом Job](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule/blob/bd9cbe52d551e4eb855ad836635311e22c55df5b/lib/Invocation.js#L224) в node-schedule, а вот что [под капотом long-timeout](https://github.com/tellnes/long-timeout/blob/236f21383aed9fa420f855a86b4f6c4f805d24a2/index.js#L44), так что стоило бы перепридумать вывод о неадекватности

Comment: Если предполагается обрабатывать много записей синхронно после получения из БД, то лучше использовать шедулер с возможностью выполнения в отдельном воркер треде, например bree